# Service worker caching after domain transfer

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

I have a client that created a site (let's say example.com) that was built with create-react-app and used service workers to cache the site.

This client has now transferred the domain (example.com) for the create-react-app to a Wordpress site. So, now example.com should display content for the Wordpress site instead of the create-react-app application.

However, users that have previously visited the create-react-app version of the site only see a blank page because the service worker is caching the create-react-app application and failing to load the main javascript file for the React application.

I understand how we can manually force a cache reload; however, most visitors won't know the steps required to unregister the service worker. They will probably just think the site isn't working because they see a blank white page.

Does anyone know how to correct this issue for previous visitors of example.com automatically without them having to manually unregister the service worker?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Our solution was a big hack. I put a file on the WordPress site with the exact name the service worker was looking for and in that file, I added code to unregister the service worker. It only worked for my client because there was only a single release.

Comment: Okay cool. In my case it got fixed after I waited 24 hours after the release. It seems like there's some caching in the service worker itself.